# Is there a way to affect a statement that will be used later in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

I am not sure how clear the title is. I am working on creating an `ArrayList` (specifically for `String`s) in Java, and I want to merge `removeAll()` and `retainAll()` into one method. This is what I have:

```
@Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return removeSome(c, true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return removeSome(c, false);
    }
```

And for the method itself:

```
private boolean removeSome(Collection<? extends String> c, boolean remove) { //remove vs retain
        collectionIsNullCheck(c);

        if (c.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        int newInsertionPoint = 0;
        boolean changed = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < insertionPoint; i++) {
            
            if (remove) { //remove
                if (!c.contains(backingStore[i])) {
                    backingStore[newInsertionPoint++] = backingStore[i];
                    
                    //this check is here because maybe backingStore and c don't intersect
                    if (!changed)
                        changed = true;
                }
            } else { //retain
                if (c.contains(backingStore[i])) {
                    backingStore[newInsertionPoint++] = backingStore[i];
                    
                    if (!changed)
                        changed = true;
                }
            }
        }

        Arrays.fill(backingStore, newInsertionPoint, backingStore.length - 1, null);
        insertionPoint = newInsertionPoint;

        return changed;
    }
```

What I am curious about is whether there is some way to not duplicate the entire code block of

```
if (!c.contains(backingStore[i])) {
    backingStore[newInsertionPoint++] = backingStore[i];
                    
    //this check is here because maybe backingStore and c don't intersect
    if (!changed)
        changed = true;
}
```

I considered something like

```
if ((remove && !c.contains(backingStore[i])) || (!remove && c.contains(backingStore[i]))) {
    ...
}
```

But I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Well, you could have `if (c.contains(backingStore[i]) != remove) {`  but that's horrible ;)   Better to refactor out to a separate method perhaps.    But more interesting : Does `removeSome` actually work?  Why do you have `backingStore` as an array - so much nicer if it was a List.

Comment: Because I am building an `ArrayList` from the ground up, `backingStore` is an `array`, because no `List` has ever been implemented.

Comment: Fair enough :)  Incidentally, I'd think you want `changed = true` if the backingStore has changed - ie, if even one entry is being discarded.  At present, it looks to be being set if even one element is being retained.

Comment: I didn't notice that. That's a point in the favor of two separate blocks - flip the flag if the statement triggers in `retain`, and if it does not in `remove`

Comment: Actually, I suppose I could take that out and at the end put ```boolean changed = insertionPoint != newInsertionPoint;```